# Dynamics CRM Get Current Organization Name

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I need to get the current organization name inside of an aspx page in the ISV directory. The only example I've seen of this tries to parse it out of the URL or the domain name, but the URL doesn't have the current org name because the page is in the ISV directory...and the domain name doesn't have it period in my case.

How can I get the org name?

I need this so that I can call CrmAuthenticationToken.ExtractCrmAuthenticationToken.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "current" organization in an ASP.NET page as long as you do not have an initialized CrmService. You will of course want it to be the organization that is being used within the browser instance from which the page was called, but that will have to be passed in the page's QueryString from which you can get it via `Request.QueryString["orgname"]` (or whatever you call the QueryString parameter).

Comment: How do I get it to pass me that query string parameter?

Comment: That depends on where the page is called from. If it's an IFrame in an entity form, there's a checkbox to enable passing additional parameters in the form editor; one of those will be `orgname`. If the page is inserted via Sitemap or ISV.config, the tag will allow for an attribute called `PassParams` to achieve the same thing. If you set the URL yourself via JavaScript, there will be a variable called `ORG_UNIQUE_NAME` in any CRM window that contains the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SQL Server database of CRM you can execute following select:

```
SELECT [UniqueName] FROM [MSCRM_CONFIG].[dbo].[Organization]
```

Comment: This does not help in the context of the question. This statement simply returns the unique names of all existing organizations.

Comment: might be helpful if you have only one organisation